# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import data to MySQL, Lost connection to MySQL server during querys occur

Tags: mysql

I had a 56G csv local file with 45W+ columns, and wanted to use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" command to import data to remote MySQL server. It took so long and then raise an error "Lost connection to MySQL server during querys..." Is it my file too big so it takes so long time to use LOCAL upload? Or other reasons? How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to up the `connect_timeout` and `wait_timeout` settings in your mysql server configuration. Or if it's possible split your file into several separate files with less data and import one by one.